# How can I programmatically target the application of a logo in an image

Tags: c#, image, detection

I'm wanting to target the spot to place a logo on an existing image. So I have a ton of different images of shirts. I want to take the user's supplied logo and locate on the shirt where to place the logo.

I already composite logos just fine. But I'm finding that not every shirt photo is identical or proportional. So using set coordinates doesn't always work.

I fiddled around with edge detection. So, okay, now I have the image in black with a white border around the shirt... I'm lost as to where to take edge detection next and how to plot the target area. Or whether that's just the wrong approach all together.

I'm working in C#. But I can probably convert from any other language suggestions come in.

Comment: Depending on how clean the edge detection is, you could calculate a bounding box around the shirt by finding the lowest and highest x and y coordinates of white pixels.  That could help you center the logo.

Answer (score 0):

I just went ahead and skipped the overly detailed edge detection I was doing and used AForge's .Net library to detect corners of the shirt and then get the binding rectangle of those corners. Then I'll work from there with standard offsets. This should get me where I need to go. Hopefully.

```
        AForge.Imaging.SusanCornersDetector scd = new AForge.Imaging.SusanCornersDetector();
        List<AForge.IntPoint> corners = scd.ProcessImage(FilterMap);
        AForge.IntPoint XYMin, XYMax;
        AForge.Math.Geometry.PointsCloud.GetBoundingRectangle(corners, out XYMin, out XYMax);

        Console.WriteLine("min X: " + XYMin.X.ToString() + " Y: " + XYMin.Y.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine("max X: " + XYMax.X.ToString() + " Y: " + XYMax.Y.ToString());
```